# Mongodb: return matched filters when using $or in find()

Tags: mongodb, filter, find, match

Suppose I am doing a query in Mongodb like this

```
db.user.find({$or : [{"field1" : "abc"}, {"field2" : "def"}, {"field3" : "ghi"}]})
```

And a number of documents are returned. What is the easiest way to know which one (or multiple) of the three filters is matched for each document returned? By "easiest", I do not wish to add more executions of find()'s.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option to solve this on the MongoDB query layer. Likely you want to perform individual queries instead one big $or query in order to solve your problem.