# Combine two OR-queries with AND in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to combine two OR-queries with AND in Monoose, like in this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE (a = 1 OR b = 1) AND (c=1 OR d=1)
```

I tried this in a NodeJS module which only gets the model object from the main application:

```
/********** Main application ***********/
var query = MyModel.find({});
myModule1.addCondition(query);
myModule2.addCondition(query);
query.exec(...)

/************ myModule1 ***************/
exports.addCondition = function(query) {
  query.or({a: 1}, {b: 1});
}

/************ myModule2 ***************/
exports.addCondition = function(query) {
  query.or({c: 1}, {d: 1});
}
```

But this doesn't work, all OR-conditions will get joined together like in this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE a = 1 OR b = 1 OR c=1 OR d=1
```

How can I combine the two conditions of `myModule1` and `myModule2` with AND in Mongoose?

Comment: Typo: `query.or({a: 1}, {b: 1});` should be something like `query.or([{a: 1}, {b: 1}]);` etc.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create your query object directly as:

```
  Test.find({
      $and: [
          { $or: [{a: 1}, {b: 1}] },
          { $or: [{c: 1}, {d: 1}] }
      ]
  }, function (err, results) {
      ...
  }
```

But you can also use the [`Query#and`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-and) helper that's available in recent 3.x Mongoose releases:

```
  Test.find()
      .and([
          { $or: [{a: 1}, {b: 1}] },
          { $or: [{c: 1}, {d: 1}] }
      ])
      .exec(function (err, results) {
          ...
      });
```

Comment: Is there a way to find in $or statement which condition worked(satisfied). @johnnyHK

Comment: @VishAl Nope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631205/mongodb-return-matched-filters-when-using-or-in-find

Comment: i think you can use $or directly without need for $and

Comment: yeah! as Hisham said it should work without '$and' mongoose takes every comma as a '$and'. can someone say it does?

Comment: You need to use `$and` here because you can't have two fields in an object with the same name (of `$or`).