# Mongo Distinct Count and Where

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need help with running a Distinct, Count and Where query in Mongo.
Collection is called **'trackedevents'**

```
{
    Type: 'Asset Search',
    User: 'ABC'
    Timestamp: '26/01/2015'
},
{
    Type: 'Asset Search',
    User: 'DEF'
    Timestamp : '27/01/2015'
}
```

What I need help with is getting mongo to give me a **Count** of **Unique Users** within a certain **Timestamp** range where the **Type** is  **'Asset Search'**

I could do this in SQL relatively easily but mongo just feels more convoluted.  Can some of the experts here help me with this.

Comment: No its just me being lazy il update it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this in a couple of ways. The first would be to use the aggregation framework which uses the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline steps for querying and grouping the documents by the 
user field to then get the count:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "Type": "Asset Search",
            "Timestamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$User",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
];

TrackedEvent.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result){
    if (err) { /* Handle error */ }
    console.log(result);
})
```

The other way is to use a combination of the **[`distinct()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct)** and **[`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-_count)** methods

```
var query = {
        "Type": "Asset Search",
        "Timestamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
    };
TrackedEvent.distinct('User', query).count().exec(function (err, count) {
    console.log('The number of unique users is: %d', count);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find()
      .and([{'Type': 'Asset Search'},
               $and: [
                       {'Timestamp': {$gt: date1}},
                       {'Timestamp': {$lt: date2}}
                     ]
      .count()
      .exec(function (err, userCount) {
         //do stuff
      })
```

If you want a range between 2 dates you may have to add a second and condition in the and. At the moment with this query yo will get the count of all users with an timestamp greater the req.params.date and type "asset search". also is your timestamp field really a array of timestamps?

//Edit now its like you wished

Comment: Is this valid for mongo though as running find().and() fails.

Comment: Of course it is look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272824/combine-two-or-queries-with-and-in-mongoose i also added my answer